# Java Generic Re-/Combination

Tags: java, generics

Given a generic function like this:

```
   <C0 extends Collection<A>, C1 extends Collection<B>, A, B> void foo(C0 a, C1 b);
```

**Question 1:** How do I enforce, that C0 and C1 are **exactly** the same collection-type?

**Question 2:** The syntax of the code shown below is wrong, but is there a way to archieve this?

*I would like to be able to write something like this. It is shorter and more understandable.*

```
<C extends Collection, A, B> void foo(C<A> a, C<B> b);
```

Comment: Goal 1 is impossible to achieve with a static check. You need the actual runtime types for that. Two Collection arguments might actually be a List and a Set. Two Set arguments could actually be a HashSet and a TreeSet. Two HashSet arguments could actually be a HashSet and some HashSet subclass.

Comment: The real question is, why do `C0` and `C1` *need* to be the same type?

Comment: Can you clarify Question 1? Do you mean that C0 and C1 can be ArrayList<Integer> and ArrayList<Double>, and they can't be ArrayList<Integer> and HashSet<Integer>?

Comment: @sisyphus I mean, that if C0 is an ArrayList, C1 has to be a ArrayList too, and no subtype of it.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is a total hack, but...

You could use overloading to provide, say a List version, a Set version, etc. And clearly, you could make them *exactly* the same, by going to the extreme of providing implementations of the concrete types, rather than their interface types.

Sometimes libraries do similar things using a pre-compilation step that generates the code.

Or, (another hack), you could perhaps create a class that holds two columns and parameterize *that* type with a single generic.